# Creating a pre-recorded lecture on macOS

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video, video-editing, screen-recording

I have created a PowerPoint presentation and I want to create a video of me presenting it. I'm looking for a software to make my life easier. The features I'm looking for are:

1. Can record a 25-minute video for free.
2. Works on Mac.
3. Can record the screen and me (audio+video).
4. Lets me rewind while recording and continue from there, so that if I make a tiny mistake I can just go a few seconds (or one slide) back and continue recording.

This is not a regular opinion-base recommendation question, because I haven't found even one software that answers these needs. PowerPoint for Mac doesn't record video (only audio) and the built-in screenshot program doesn't record it either. I can use zoom and share my screen and record, but feature number 4 isn't supported.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need [video editing software](https://www.bing.com/search?form=MOZLBR&pc=MOZI&q=opensource+video+editor) if it's going to be pre-recorded. [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) is good stuff and fits your needs, but allocate time to learn how to use it.  No software capable of your requirements is going to be "install and make video in 5 mins" type of thing especially when you put the requirement of "free."

Comment: What you are looking for is OBS Studio, it's free, can record you and multiple sources such as the screen, a window, etc.  You would still have to edit so instead of rewinding you just start over and redo the portion you made the mistake on. Then OBS saves a video such as an MP4. You then edit that with another tool. Apple iMovie is easy to use and free. Just cut out the bad parts and stitch it back together. Add transitions. Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: @JamesBrickley, thank you, to record without rewinding I guess I can just use zoom, share my screen and record.

Comment: @Allan thanks, does OpenShot support requirement number 4? (rewinding while recording)

Comment: @Elia Sharankanski - Yes, Zoom works. Using it at work to record. OBS gives you a lot more options. OBS is what the YouTubers use to live stream and record video podcasts. OBS can do quite a bit more than Zoom. The biggie being the use of various scenes and transitions and making it look more professional. Switch between a slide deck and a small thumbnail of you speaking to a split screen with a larger you and some content on the side, etc. Multiple cameras, video clips, etc., etc.

Comment: I don't recommend OBS for what you want to do.  OBS is short for Open *Broadcast* Software meaning live.  If you intend to pre-record your session, make edits like go back before your mistake, edit it out and continue on, the OpenShot is your product.  So, yes, OpenShot supports #4

Comment: @Allan I've just read about OpenShot and it seems like it's just for editing, it doesn't even record your screen. Am I right?

Comment: @JamesBrickley It sounds very professional indeed but I just need to record a simple lecture, as a one-time thing, so I want something simple and fast. This is for a theoretical computer science conference so it isn't supposed to look that fancy.

Comment: You record your screen with whatever utility you use.  If you make a mistake, you stop, and redo it.  You use OpenShot to edit out the mistake.  If you make 5 different recordings from your screen to a camera on you, you use OpenShot to bring them all together.

Comment: Your coming into the world of video editing.  You need software to record (Screen Capture or Quick Time built into the Mac) and software for *post production.*. Photographers use a camera and then something like Photoshop for post.  You need to use whatever your going to use to record the video and use OpenShot for post.  There's a lot to video editing and it's way too much for a question here and the comments is definitely  not a good venue for teaching this topic.  You might want to try Lynda.com or Coursera (or similar) for tutorials.

Comment: @Allan thanks, there's a good chance that's what I'll do eventually. I just really wanted to avoid all that editing trouble. I'm not a native English speaker and the lecture has to be in English, so it would be great if I could just press the left arrow every time I get stuck or say a word with a weird accent, then press the space button to listen to the recording in order to find the exact place, and then press another button to start recording again. Editing a tiny mistake every 30 seconds is going to take a lot of time...

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing like that (at least that I know of).

Comment: @Allan I've edited videos before using windows video maker (simple edits), so I don't think this is going to be a problem, also this is just a one-time thing so I don't need to become a professional :) Just really hoped for a tool that does what I asked for. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Try with QuickTime.  It might do what you want.

Comment: @Allan I tried, it can either record the screen or record me. And it doesn't have feature number #4. By the way, on windows, PowerPoint can record a presentation together with narration and a video of my face, and it then divides the recording by slides and you can re-record just one slide easily. Unfortunately this doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: Since schools are going online, this question is relevant now & outlines the demands of  the teachers. The requirements are clear in the post and there are some suggestions in comments too that can be made answers.

Answer (score 2):

The fourth point about rewinding video and re-recording is unheard of. Let's say you made a minor mistake while speaking, best you can do is one or more of the following:

- Open the video editor, add a text box that shows the correct thing to say, make it visible in the video as an overlapping window for 3-4 seconds. This is a common method to fix mistakes in post-shoot editing.
- When you realise that you've made a mistake, immediately repeat the last sentence with the correct word and let the recording go on. While editing it later on, trim the portion where you misspoke and delete that part. There will be an slightly abrupt cut but not a big deal in lectures.

All this is possible in iMovie for macOS. It's free and easy to use. Also use help centre: https://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.1/#/mov5ec96da08

For screen recording, Quicktime is a good option. If you want to appear speaking in the video, use Photo Booth and put it in a corner such that it appears on the screen.

Other way is to use a camera and use clips from both the camera and the screen in the final video.

Comment: Thank you, these are good and helpful ideas. However, I would really like to know if there exists a program that does have the fourth requirement. That would really make my life easier and save me a lot of editing time. Even something that integrates with PowerPoint and lets me re-record a specific slide would be nice.

Comment: I am not aware of any such app unfortunately

Comment: Have you looked into Keynote as a replacement for PowerPoint?  I don't know if it does all you want but playing and recording are nice.

Comment: @jmh best to post an answer.. I have no experience with keynote

Answer (score 0):

For freeware with no time limit, [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com) is recommended by many. However, since it's too complicated to learn, I'm now using [RecMaster](https://www.recmaster.net/how-to/screen-recorder-for-macos-11) for easier presentation video creation.